# ASP MVC - Creating Custom Modules

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I've created an MVC2 CMS with basic functionality, which we hope to give to clients.

What I would like to know is how to create drop-in modules specific to the clients which are extension to the basic functions but core to the clients specific needs. e.g. One client might have specific reports and another client may want additional fields added to the content area.

If anyone knows of a good place to start looking then I would be grateful if you can let me know.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Portable Areas feature on MvcContrib.  Works as you've described.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, it certainly is what I need. kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

The new Orchard CMS is build on ASP.Net MVC and is open source. So you could have a look at their code.